# Open accordion menu items with sticky scroll menu links

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I have a accordion menu and sticky scroll links which are working absolutely fine individually.

What I need to do now is to link the scroll menu to accordion so that it will open up the accordion tab when clicking on accordion menu and sticky scroll menu both.

I need to make accordion menu to get opened when user click on the scrolling menu items as well.

How do I link the toggle function dynamically to sticky scroll menu also?

I haven't used any plugins for these two so please suggest me to do without plugin. Thank you.

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
  //Sticky scroll menu
  var top = $('.sticky-scroll-box').offset().top;
  $(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (y >= top) {
          $('.sticky-scroll-box').addClass('fixed');
        } else {
          $('.sticky-scroll-box').removeClass('fixed');
        }
        $('.sticky-scroll-box').width($('.sticky-scroll-box').parent().width());
    });

    //Accordion
    $(".menu_body").hide();
    //toggle the componenet with class menu_body
    $(".menu_head").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".menu_body").slideToggle(400); 
        var plusmin;
        plusmin = $(this).children(".plusminus").text();

        $(this).children("span.down-arrow").toggleClass("up-arrow");        
    });

});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/orAKEVu/5/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a linking between sticky menu and accordion menu using any attribute value

```
  //toggle the componenet with sticky menu
  $('.sticky-scroll-box a').click(function(){
    var menuRef = $(this).attr('toggelink');    
    $(".menu_head").filter("[toggelink^='"+menuRef+"']").click();    
  });
});
```

and change the html like

```
<a toggelink="menu_1" class="menu_head"> Menu 1</a>
```

for sticky menu

```
<a toggelink="menu_1"  href="#">Menu 1</a>
```

these attributes you can create dynamicaly in the rendering logic.

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/uRONusiY/1)**

One more approach is to take the `index` of menu item , means find the `nth` number of menu you are clicking in stick and trigger a click to accordion menu item with same `nth` number

With href-id linking [**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/uRONusiY/2), create the ids dynamically in rendering logic

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. The main part is it menu content should scroll up when clicking on the sticky menu, otherwise user wont be knowing it is opened up right. Any idea?  Content inside the menu is very long so

Comment: that you can add with href-id linking in a simple way. `http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3` , create the ids dynamically in rendering logic